# How to bind dataGridView predefined columns with columns from sql statement (without adding new columns)?

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview, datatable, dataview

Is there a elegant way, to bind predefined dataGridView columns with results from a SQL statement?

Example:

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("EID", "ID");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("FName", "FirstName");
```

Some SQL like

```
SELECT t.FirstName AS FName, t.EmpID AS EID 
FROM table t ...
```

and then I call

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = someDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

The last call add columns to my datagrid but I just want to bind it by column name not to add new columns.

The example will give a result like this:

Table columns: ID, FirstName, FName, EID (ID and FirstName holds empty cells)

How to get this:

```
Table columns: ID, FirstName or FirstName, ID
```

Best regards!

Answer (score 22):

Use `dataGridView1.Columns["FName"].DataPropertyName = "FName"` where **FName** is column in your data table.

Comment: This solves the problem, your answer should be marked as correct.

Answer (score 17):

Aside from setting `AutoGenerateColumns` to false, you also need to set `DataPropertyName` for each column in the `DataGridView` to the corresponding field in the data source.  You can set this in the designer or in code before setting the `DataSource` property.

Comment: When you add a column it only sets the column name and header -- Not  the DataPropertyName.

Answer (score 4):

I think the DataGridView has an `AutoGenerateColumns` property, doesn't it?

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True;
```

From the MSDN docs:

> public bool AutoGenerateColumns { set;
>   get; }
>       Member of System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
>
> Summary: Gets or sets a value
>   indicating whether columns are created
>   automatically when the
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataSource
>   or
>   System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataMember
>   properties are set.
>
> Returns: true if the columns should be
>   created automatically; otherwise,
>   false. The default is true.

The property isn't on the Properties window though, you have to set it via code as in my example.

Comment: Neil, tried dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = True; and = false, but the same result. Doesn't work.

Comment: Are you setting AutoGenerateColumns **before** setting DataSource or DataMember, as per the docs?

Comment: Tried to set it before and after setting DataSource and still not what I need.

Comment: The columns now are ok, but the rows are empty.

Comment: Also the row count is ok, only the cells are empty.

Comment: Cool! Solved the problem with your help! I have added rows to DataGrid programmly as List from the XAML.CS file, with previously initilalized DataGrid in XAML with the `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`. On the Run, all the inialized columns were filled with values, but new columns with variables names in header also were created. Setting the attribute False removed this problem.

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing WinForm, the important part is setting the `DataPropertyName` property to match the DataTable Column name. You can do it in the designer or code as follows:

```
Me.AccountDataGridView.Columns("Account").DataPropertyName = "Account"
```

Of course, having set this:

```
Me.AccountDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

Answer (score 0):

How about adding columns to the Columns tag of your gridview like so?

```
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="EID" HeaderText="ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="FName" HeaderText="First name" />
...
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using winforms!